# Open graph warnings when validating page with facebook object debugger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have those open graph tags on [demo.outsourceproject.co.uk](http://demo.outsourceproject.co.uk):

```
<meta content='Demo Shop' property='og:title'>
<meta content='restaurant' property='og:type'>
<meta content='http://demo.lvh.me:3000/images/screenshots/layouts/005_small.jpg' property='og:image'>
<meta content='http://demo.lvh.me:3000/categories/15-starters' property='og:url'>
<meta content='demo@ordys.co.uk' property='og:email'>
<meta content='02010203040' property='og:phone_number'>
<meta content='78 York Street  ' property='og:street-address'>
<meta content='London' property='og:locality'>
<meta content='W1H 1DP' property='og:postal-code'>
<meta content='United Kingdom' property='og:country-name'>
```

When I [validate it with](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.outsourceproject.co.uk%2Fcategories%2F13-starters) with facebook object debugger it reports warnings like:

```
Extraneous Property:Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:email.
```

Do you have any idea why og:email, og:locality etc it is not allowed for og:type=restaurant?

Thanks,

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are all deprecated. See http://ogp.me/ for the markup.

You can make your own schema's using the Open Graph section of the developer app. http://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: I got it now. On https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ it says: "This is the current production version of the Open Graph and will work with the Like Button and other social plugins". Obviously they are preparing for a new version and thus the warning. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

is there a better url for us to look at?

"Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped."

I'm thinking you might have a 301/302 redirect happening.  I don't think the linter tool likes to do 302 redirects.

Comment: try this one https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.outsourceproject.co.uk%2Fcategories%2F13-starters