# Domain blocked and no data scraped

Tags: facebook, dns, sharing, blocked

I recently purchased the domain www.iacro.dk from UnoEuro and installed WordPress planning to integrate blogging with Facebook. However, I cannot even get to share a link to the domain.

When I try to share any link on my timeline, it gives the error "The content you're trying to share includes a link that's been blocked for being spammy or unsafe: iacro.dk". Searching, I came across [Sucuri SiteCheck](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net) which showed that McAfee TrustedSource had marked the site as having malicious content. Strange considering that I just bought it, it contains nothing but WordPress and I can't find any previous history of ownership. But I got McAfee to reclassify it and it now shows up green at SiteCheck. However, now a few days later, Facebook still blocks it. Clicking the "let us know" link in the FB block dialog got me to a "Blocked from Adding Content" form that I submitted, but this just triggered a confirmation mail stating that individual issues are not processed.

I then noticed the same behavior as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190649/site-not-valid-but-it-is) and [here](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11843242/site-url-blocked-as-spammy-but-also-no-data-was-scraped-in-debug): When I type in any iacro.dk link on my Timeline it generates a blank preview with "(No Title)". It doesn't matter if it's the front page, a htm document or even an image - nothing is returned. So I tried the debugger which returns the very generic "Error Parsing URL: Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.". Searching on this site, a lot of people suggest that missing "og:" tags might cause no scraping. I installed a WP plugin for that and verified tag generation, but nothing changed. And since FB can't even scrape plain htm / jpg from the domain, I assume tags can be ruled out.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631411/open-graph-warnings-when-validating-page-with-facebook-object-debugger) someone suggests 301 Redirects being a problem, but I haven't set up redirection - I don't even have a .htaccess file.

So, my questions are: Is this all because of the domain being marked as "spammy"? If so, how can I get the FB ban lifted? However, I have seen examples of other "spammy" sites where the preview is being generated just fine, e.g. http://dagbok.nu described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10190649/site-not-valid-but-it-is). So if the blacklist is not the only problem, what else is wrong?

This is driving me nuts so thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Probably your best bet is to file a [bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) on this. The "create a bug" link appears when you start typing in the search box.

Comment: That's what I feared. I'll give it a shot, but all similar bugs have been closed with comments like "Closing as this is not a platform bug.". Makes it very difficult to do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details, but it is a problem that facebook has with web sites hosted on shared servers, i.e. the server hosting your web site also hosts a number of other web sites.